# Milliseconds format in maven.build.timestamp

Tags: plugins, maven-2, timestamp, pom.xml

this is my scenario, it's pretty simple but am afraid it took me 2 days already.

In my pom.xml, I have this set of properties.

```
<properties>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd-HHmmssSSS</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

The format is fine because I've got milliseconds in it, however, I wanted to have just milliseconds, like the one returned in,

```
date.getTime();
```

Can we do that in Maven plugins? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can have a look at this plugin: http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-timestamp-mojo.html. By default, it returns time in milliseconds.